# why sortedBy function is duplicating my list?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I need to do two processes on my list of `DirectMessages`

1.`mark last messages`

2.`sort by timestamp descending`

they are doing well when I do one of them at the time
but when I do both in same time, some of items in the list duplicated; here you can see my code:

```kotlin
fun List<DirectMessage>.doProcesses(): List<DirectMessage> {
    for (i in this.indices) {
        if (i == 0) {
            this[i].isLastMessage = true
            continue
        }
        this[i].isLastMessage =
            this[i - 1].senderUserId != this[i].senderUserId
    }
    return sortedByDescending { it.timestamp }
}
```

and the `DirectMessage` data class:

```kotlin
data class DirectMessage(
    val messageId: Int,
    val text: String,
    val timestamp: Long,
    val senderUserId: Int,
    var isLastMessage: Boolean = true
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the Kotlin functions prefixed with `sortedBy` produce a new list that represents a sorted copy of your original list.

What you're looking for is an in-place sort, which can be achieved using the `sortBy` functions. However these obviously work on mutable data structures like `MutableList` or `Array`.

Comment: if you see more carefully you can see that my extension function is returning new instance of the list. I use that like this : `myList = myList.doProcesses()` and it should not duplicate my list's items.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicating the items? Can you give a simple example of what it produces and what you want instead?

Comment: assume this `myList = [message1, message2, message3]`. when I use `myList = myList.doProcesses()` this is the result: `[message3, message3, message2, message2, message1, message1]`

Comment: I have tried your example and unfortunately I don't get the same results, I still get a list returned with the same number of elements. You must be modifying the list elsewhere, your code can't possibly return more items than it started with.

Comment: Yeah you were right. I was modifying the list elsewhere. thanks for the help